# How to get all the array values when searching particular values in tableview cell using Obejctive C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have implemented a TableView with custom cells with two labels to populate city name and city id (I kept the city id label hidden). Here my problem is when I search for the city name I cannot get the city id also, when I search the city name, I want both the values to be filtered.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     static NSString *cellidentifier=@"citylocation";
        searchTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell= [[searchTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
        }
        if(!isFilltered)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [avahotel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.city.text = [[createdDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]stringValue];
        }else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [filteredString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }    
    return cell;  
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(isFilltered)
    {
        return [filteredString count];
    }
    return [avahotel count];
}
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if(searchText.length == 0)
    {
        isFilltered = NO;
    }else
    {
        isFilltered = YES;
        filteredString = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(NSString *str in avahotel)
        {
            NSRange stringRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if(stringRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [filteredString addObject:str];
            }
        }
    }
    [_searchtableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I have a question here. Do you want to have the information about the city id in the filteredString array? When actually searching for the city name? Or did I misunderstood?

Comment: Searching City name and all working fine,My need is,How to filter both the label.For example if I am searching Chennai means,i want both Chennai and city id(100)  values .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code in else part for this method.  searchBar textDidChange

**Updated**

```
    isFilltered = YES;
    filteredString = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    filteredCityId = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(Int i=0; i<avahotel.count; i++)
    {
       NSString *str = [avahotel objectAtIndex:i]; 
        NSRange stringRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if(stringRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [filteredString addObject:[avahotel objectAtIndex:i]]; 
            NSString *strId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]; 
            [filteredCityId addObject:strId]

            // here your both filter array declare.filteredcityId and filteredString           
        }
     }
```

Comment: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cityname...I got this error .here avahotel is my array which contains all cityname

Comment: Can you share avahotel ("print data response") array here? so l'll get solution for this error.

Comment: The Available hotel is (
    AGRA,
    BANGALORE,
    CHENNAI,
    GOA,
    HYDERABAD,
    JAIPUR,
    KOLKATA,
    "MUMBAI / BOMBAY",
    "NEW DELHI",
    AGARTALA,
    AHMEDABAD,
    AIZAWL,
    AJMER,
    AKOLA,
    ALIBAG,
    ALLAHABAD,
    ALLEPPEY,
    ALMORA,
    ALSISAR,
    ALWAR,
    AMBALA,
    AMLA,
    AMRITSAR,
    ANAND,
    ANKLESWAR,
    ARONDA,
    ASHTAMUDI,
}

Comment: The city id is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....} If I search Chennai means I need according cityID (3) also..

Comment: @ShubamGupta Okay understand you code! I update my code pls use this. Hope will helpful to you

Comment: Okay Great!! Happy coding. :D